# Get exception stacktrace as output from Oozie Java Action

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a java action running on Oozie. I would like to get complete Java Exception in case this java action fails.
The Java action simply uses a jar file . Here is the java action

```
<workflow-app name='proj-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
    <start to='startIndex'/>
    <action name='startIndex'>
       <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        <main-class>com.myproj.MyDriverJob</main-class>
            <arg>-Dlww.commit.on.close=true</arg>

            <capture-output/>
        </java>
        <ok to='end'/>
        <error to='end'/>
    </action>
    <kill name='kill'>
    <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}] </message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

How does it sends back the error occurred in my java class.
I am looking for a way to send exception stacktrace back to my server.

Comment: You can simply look hadoop log file to see the exception stack trace.

Comment: @Asankasanjaya updated the question . I am looking for a way to send exception stacktrace back to my server.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"my server"_ > you mean add to the Oozie job log (not feasible AFAIK), or send an alert to some custom monitoring app w/ the stack as payload (not feasible from YARN AFAIK)?

Comment: Remember that Oozie submits your job to an external, distributed system (YARN); then it just polls YARN from time to time to get the status. Not the details.

Comment: If you are one of the brave, you can retrieve the YARN job ID from Oozie (cf. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.3_Workflow_EL_Functions but beware of the legacy `job_` vs newer `application_` prefix mismatch) and build some custom code to request log details from YARN using its REST API, parse it, send it somewhere, etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I am interested more in the Exception that caused the oozie job to kill rather than complete logs

Comment: Yeah, but the Exception sits there in the logs, in plain text. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `System.exit(int n)` in your java class as this will make the java action to do an error transition.

This way, you can get excpetion stacktrace in case of Java action failure.

Comment: Will I get the error message in ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}

Comment: yeah, you can get the error message using above code

Answer (score 0):

Handle all exceptions in your Java code, and in each catch block, set an Oozie property key (say, `Error`) to the exception text (e.g., `e.toString()`). Exit using `System.exit(0)`. (For now, it seems that exiting with `System.exit(1)` prevents Oozie from capturing the output.) For details on how Oozie can capture output from a Java action, see [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Java+Cookbook).

You can then access `Error` in your Oozie workflow, and email it to yourself using the [Email action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_EmailActionExtension.html).

Tip: A better way to handle exceptions in your code would be to have a global singleton `ErrorHandler` class that sets the Oozie `Error` property.